# Getting data with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

so what's i'm looking for it is how to getting this informations (with blue) and print it on my command line application [Classement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACf5c.png)
I tryed this:

```js
var cloudscraper = require('cloudscraper');


cloudscraper.post('https://hbeta.net/', {
  username: "Hidden",
  password: "Hidden"
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error");
  } else {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    cloudscraper.get('hbeta.net/community/classement', function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error occurred');
      } else {
        console.log(body);
        //here i dont know what to do to get the  specific information from the body
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please format code so that it is easily readable? -- What does `console.log(body)` display in the console?

Comment: Like this @nicovank?

Comment: I assume `body` is HTML; the way you get what you have in the screenshot depends on what's in the body; we can't answer that for you unless we also see what the HTML contains.

Comment: <tr>
                                  <td class="un">
                                      <div class="user avatar" style="background-image: url(http://habbo.fr/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=lg-281-1408.sh-295-94.ch-215-94.ha-5347-64.hd-180-1359.hr-3163-31&amp;size=s); float: left; display: inline-block;"></div>
                                      <div style="margin: 6px; display: inline-block;">Falque</div>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="un">105 points</td>
                              </tr> 
@Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you would do what is called web scraping. `cheerio` is a node module that would allow you to do that.

You can find [a tutorial here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to console.log after cloudscraper function

```
var cloudscraper = require('cloudscraper');


cloudscraper.post('https://hbeta.net/', {
  username: "Hidden",
  password: "Hidden"
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error");
  } else {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    cloudscraper.get('hbeta.net/community/classement').then(console.log, console.error);
  }
});
```